# Problem accessing custom metrics sent by opencensus exporter

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-run, opencensus

I would like to export custom metrics using the opencensus python exporter as described in:  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census

I have a flask application deployed on **Google Cloud Run** that uses the piece of code in example.
When I deploy the service, everything seems to be ok (the **Exporting stats to project**  log indicates the correct project id), and then no exception is thrown by the exporter at any time. The **mmap.record()** method is also called without error.

However, I don't manage to retrieve any value from ***Metrics Explorer***, nor using the ***metricDescriptors API*** (searching for ***task_latency_distribution***). Monitoring API is activated on my project, and as far as I understood there is no need to create the metric through the API since the exporter should do it by itself.

My questions are:

- Are custom metrics compatible with Google Cloud Run deployment?
- Is there is way to check/debug what is sent by the exporter?

Or more basically, does anybody have any clue of what can go wrong with test :-)?

Thanks for your help,

Aurelien

Comment: If you search for any metrics that starts with `custom.googleapis.com/` do you see any results?

Comment: Yes there are some, but not the one I created and all of them seem to be related to gce_instances.

Comment: If you are not receiving any error log on your code, this can be related with something at ingestion time on GCP side, I recommend you open a [support case](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) or a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Cloud Run throttles CPU to ~0 when it's not processing requests. Systems like OC exporters tend to upload trace spans in the background periodically. On Cloud Run you should handle SIGTERM signal and call Flush() on the exporter if that's provider to upload spans before the container shuts down. This might help, but I don't know the "custom metrics" part.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I set to 1 the min-instances option in GCR. As far as I understood, this ensures keeping at least one container up and running. Anyway I'll try to call Flush() on the exporter to be sure, thanks for info. @Jan Hernandez: yes I will consider opening an issue on the issue tracker, thanks.

Comment: Does the project's service account that's running the Cloud Run containers have permission to write to Stackdriver Monitoring? And, can you view the metrics using Google APIs Explorer? APIs Explorer is an excellent way to debug any Google API

Comment: Yes it has. Actually I managed to make it work with a very simple flask api, but when I switch back to gunicorn it does not work anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem occurred when using the preload flag in gunicorn (after disabling the preload flags it started to work). It seems related to the way the workers are forked in gunicorn. We found a work-around to make it work with the preload flag by lazily instantiating the exporter at the first query (we are not totally satisfied by this solution and we would be glad to know if somebody else has a better approach, but at least it is working).

Hope this could help someone facing the same issue :-)

Aurelien